# no validator found for custom annotation and validation for enum springboot java8

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, annotations

Getting this error `HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint EnumChecker validating type MyEnum Check configuration for ‘myenum’`.

Using the annotation on this class to be validated, I can't do `private final String myenum` because I need to use it as an enum in order to use the function inside the enum

```
public class Request {
     @EnumChecker(enumclass = MyEnum.class)
     private final MyEnum myenum;
}
```

annotation

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyEnumValidator.class)
@Target({FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE, TYPE_USE, TYPE_PARAMETER, METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface EnumChecker {
  String message() default "must be one of these values";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
  Class<? extends Enum> enumClass();
}
```

validator

```
public class MyEnumValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EnumChecker, String> {
  private List<String> validEnumList;

  @Override
  public void initialize(EnumChecker constraintAnnotation) {
    validEnumList = Arrays.stream(constraintAnnotation.enumClass().getEnumConstants())
        .map(Enum::name)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return validEnumList.contains(value);
  }
}
```

enum

```
public enum MyEnum {

  YES, NO;

  private static final Map<MyEnum, String> MyEnumConverter =
      Map.of(YES, "yes");

  public String toMyString() {
    return MyEnumConverter.get(this);
  }

}
```

Comment: In the title you said Java 8 but you used Java 9 API.  `Map.of` was added in Java 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First delete `final` modifier in `myenum` and create setter and getter for that field, because `Jackson` is not able to bind values from http request to your `Request` class for example.

```
public class Request {
  @EnumChecker(enumClass = MyEnum.class)
  private MyEnum myenum;
  
  public MyEnum getMyenum() {
    return myenum;
  }
  
  public void setMyenum(MyEnum myenum) {
    this.myenum = myenum;
  }
}
```

**Then change `ConstraintValidator` target type to match `MyEnum` instead of `String`**

```
public class MyEnumValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EnumChecker, MyEnum> {

  private List<MyEnum> validEnumList;

  @Override
  public void initialize(EnumChecker constraintAnnotation) {
    validEnumList = Arrays.stream(constraintAnnotation.enumClass().getEnumConstants())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(MyEnum value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return validEnumList.contains(value);
  }
}
```

Test: I did the following test

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

  @PostMapping("/annot")
  public String filter(@RequestBody @Valid Request req) {
    return req.getMyenum().name();
  }
}
```

Also I changed the implementation of `MyEnumValidator` to only see validation effect and prove that it takes place. (I admit that currently this validator does not make sense. Also using **only** `@RequestBody` guarantees that `myenum` can only Have `YES` or `NO` values otherwise throws exception)

```
public class MyEnumValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EnumChecker, MyEnum> {

  private List<MyEnum> validEnumList;

  @Override
  public void initialize(EnumChecker constraintAnnotation) {
    validEnumList = Arrays.stream(constraintAnnotation.enumClass().getEnumConstants())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(MyEnum value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return validEnumList.contains(value) && value.name().length() == 3;
  }
}
```

[image]

For a invalid case:

[image]

stacktrace:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public java.lang.String api.sweater.controller.MainController.filter(api.sweater.request.Request): [Field error in object 'request' on field 'myenum': rejected value [NO]; codes [EnumChecker.request.myenum,EnumChecker.myenum,EnumChecker.api.sweater.request.MyEnum,EnumChecker]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [request.myenum,myenum]; arguments []; default message [myenum],class api.sweater.request.MyEnum]; default message [must be one of these values]] ]
```